# SQL Server CSV file import through Bulk import (not able to parse the column with double quotes and comma values)

Tags: sql-server, csv, sql-server-2017, bulk-import

I have .csv file to import into table. I am using SQL server 2017,
but here my problem is with the data I have like below:

```
column1           column2    column3 <br>
"12,23,45,67,89", TestData , 04-12-2009
```

When I am using field terminator as comma(,), from column1 value is dividing into different column value as field terminator is (,).
What I am looking here, the values which are in double quotes should be escaped from field terminator.

[image: data looks like this way]

Comment: I don't know if SQL Server has found a way to fix this problem.  When I've faced it in the past, I have been able to load the data into Excel (which actually understands full CSV formats) and recreate the table using a different delimiter (such as `'|'`).  Then it is easily imported.  I don't know why SQL Server has such problems with "real" CSV formats.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 SP1+ supports quoted identifiers in `BULK INSERT` and "true" CSV formats. If you tell us your SQL Server version, show us your attempts, and ask us a question, then the users here will be able to help you. *"Please suggest the solution."* is not a question.

Comment: @Larnu i am using SQL server 2017

Comment: Then `BULK INSERT` will work fine for your needs.

Comment: How did you try to import that data? What command, parameters did you use?

Comment: @GordonLinoff at this point it almost doesn't - 2016 is the oldest version still in mainstream support. As for previous versions, I suspect it's because they assumed everyone would use the far more powerful SSIS for import jobs. Then came the cloud-hosted versions, Linux and the virtual abandonment of SSIS

Comment: @ChiranjeeviIT the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#input-file-format-options) show you can just add `WITH ( FORMAT='CSV')` to `BULK INSERT` to load a file in the RFC 4180 standard ie double-quoted text, handling of newlines,comma for field delimiter, dot as decimal points etc

Comment: @ChiranjeeviIT on the other hand, the sample you posted is really weird. Do you really have ID columns whose contents contain *commas*???? Or is `ClientId` expected to have 5 different values in a single CSV-like string?? Was there a bug during *exporting* perhaps, and a bigint value ended up as a formatted decimal?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i need comma separated value as single value of column clientid, but there it is dividing into different column values as our delimiter is ','

Comment: @ChiranjeeviIT have you tried `FORMAT='CSV'` ? What did you actually try?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, the option `FIELDQUOTE = 'quote_characters'` should be specified

```
    BULK INSERT
       { database_name.schema_name.table_or_view_name | schema_name.table_or_view_name | table_or_view_name }
          FROM 'data_file'
         [ WITH
        (
       [ [ , ] BATCHSIZE = batch_size ]
       [ [ , ] CHECK_CONSTRAINTS ]
       [ [ , ] CODEPAGE = { 'ACP' | 'OEM' | 'RAW' | 'code_page' } ]
       [ [ , ] DATAFILETYPE =
          { 'char' | 'native'| 'widechar' | 'widenative' } ]
       [ [ , ] DATA_SOURCE = 'data_source_name' ]
       [ [ , ] ERRORFILE = 'file_name' ]
       [ [ , ] ERRORFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'data_source_name' ]
       [ [ , ] FIRSTROW = first_row ]
       [ [ , ] FIRE_TRIGGERS ]
       [ [ , ] FORMATFILE_DATASOURCE = 'data_source_name' ]
       [ [ , ] KEEPIDENTITY ]
       [ [ , ] KEEPNULLS ]
       [ [ , ] KILOBYTES_PER_BATCH = kilobytes_per_batch ]
       [ [ , ] LASTROW = last_row ]
       [ [ , ] MAXERRORS = max_errors ]
       [ [ , ] ORDER ( { column [ ASC | DESC ] } [ ,...n ] ) ]
       [ [ , ] ROWS_PER_BATCH = rows_per_batch ]
       [ [ , ] ROWTERMINATOR = 'row_terminator' ]
       [ [ , ] TABLOCK ]
    
       -- input file format options
       [ [ , ] FORMAT = 'CSV' ]
       [ [ , ] FIELDQUOTE = 'quote_characters']
       [ [ , ] FORMATFILE = 'format_file_path' ]
       [ [ , ] FIELDTERMINATOR = 'field_terminator' ]
       [ [ , ] ROWTERMINATOR = 'row_terminator' ]
    )]
```

Comment: The same page explains that's not needed if `FORMAT = 'CSV'` is used: `If not specified, the quote character (") will be used as the quote character as defined in the RFC 4180 standard.`

Comment: Not really sure about using " as default because a lot of csv files are there without any field quote. Did you try setting this option and the problem didnt solved??